# How to route an API to point to a specific controller action instead to have the welcome screen in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an API in Rails 5.2 and what I would like to achieve is that when I hit `localhost:3001` I would like to see the rendered JSON of the data my API is showing, instead of the welcome screen. I don't know how should override that welcome screen to show the URL `/api/v1/flights` immediately when I enter the localhost.

My Route looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :flights
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Comment: I used the guide but I always get route error and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I put a redirect in top doesn't work. I put root to 'flights#index' still error. I put inside the namespace but still error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your routes

```
root "api/v1/flights#index"
```